# How to aggregate one to many relation into new columns in postgres database

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, inner-join, aggregate-functions

I have this query

```
select cre.id ,string_agg(ae.name, ', ') as agents
from call_report_entity cre 
join report_agents_entity rae on cre.id = rae."reportId" 
join agent_entity ae on rae."agentId" = ae.id 
group by cre .id
order by cre.id desc
```

result:

[image]

But I need to aggregate the result to be like:

[image]

How can I achieve this result?

Comment: When asking SQL questions, please provide both sample input and expected result as tables in your question. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

For a fixed maximum number of agents per id, you can pivot with `row_number` and conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
    max(name) filter(where rn = 1) agent_1,
    max(name) filter(where rn = 2) agent_2,
    max(name) filter(where rn = 3) agent_3
from (
    select cre.id, ae.name,
        row_number() over(partition by cre.id order by ae.name) rn
    from call_report_entity cre 
    join report_agents_entity rae on cre.id = rae."reportId" 
    join agent_entity ae on rae."agentId" = ae.id
) t
group by id
order by id desc
```